# How to check state (enabled/disabled) of a form's close button

Tags: delphi, winapi

I'm disabling and enabling form's close button like in this code:

```
uses WinApi.Windows;
...
//disabling
EnableMenuItem(GetSystemMenu(MyForm.Handle, False), SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND OR MF_DISABLED);
//enabling
EnableMenuItem(GetSystemMenu(MyForm.Handle, False), SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND OR MF_ENABLED);
```

I'm trying to check if the close button's currently enabled or disabled. After checking [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/desktop/ms647578(v=vs.85).aspx) I wrote this code:

```
var
  ItemInfo : TMenuItemInfo;
  MyForm : TForm;
begin
  MyForm := GetAFormInSomeWay();
  ItemInfo.fMask := MIIM_STATE;
  GetMenuItemInfo(GetSystemMenu(MyForm.Handle, False), SC_CLOSE, False, ItemInfo);
  if(ItemInfo.fState = MFS_ENABLED)
  then ShowMessage('Enabled')
  else ShowMessage('Disabled');
```

It always shows 'Disabled' (ItemInfo.fState is always 5395358).
What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

Now it works, thanks to your suggestions.

```
uses
  WinApi.Windows, Vcl.Forms, System, System.SysUtils;

...

var
  ItemInfo : TMenuItemInfo;
  MyForm : TForm;
  SystemMenu : HMENU;
begin
  MyForm := GetAFormInSomeWay();
  ItemInfo.fMask := MIIM_STATE;
  ItemInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(MENUITEMINFO);

  SystemMenu := GetSystemMenu(MyForm.Handle, False);
  if((SystemMenu = 0) OR (GetMenuItemInfo(SystemMenu, SC_CLOSE, False, ItemInfo) = False))
  then raise Exception.Create(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError()));

  if((ItemInfo.fState AND MFS_DISABLED) = 0)
  then ShowMessage('Enabled')
  else ShowMessage('Disabled');
end;
```

Comment: A sidenote, disabling the close button should also have the `MF_GRAYED` bit set, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100604-00/?p=13803

Comment: MFS_DISABLED = MFS_GRAYED = 3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are making the classic mistake of Win32 programming. You are calling Win32 API functions and failing to check for errors. How do you know whether or not they succeed? And the answer is that you do not. Because you do not check. You must switch your mindset so that checking for errors becomes second nature when calling Win32 API functions. These functions do not raise exceptions. They signal failure by other means, typically through the return value. Find out how be reading the documentation for each function that you call.

The call to [`GetMenuItemInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms647980.aspx) fails because you do not follow the instructions in the documentation. Specifically this part covering the item info argument:

> Note that you must set the cbSize member to sizeof(MENUITEMINFO) before calling this function.

Following that instruction resolves your problem.

If you had checked for errors you would have seen that `GetMenuItemInfo` returns `False`, and `GetLastError` returns `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`.

Your code calls the following API functions: `GetSystemMenu`, `EnableMenuItem` and `GetMenuItemInfo`. You fail to check for errors in each of these calls.

You should use bitwise and to check for the flag in the state, rather than equality. Although your test worked on my system it is semantically wrong. It will fail if the item is the default item, for instance.

Frankly, the problem at hand is insignificant when compared to the importance of checking for errors. I hope you take away that lesson. So, please don't just set `cbSize` and move on, please do add error checking as well.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Feel free to tell me any further bad practise you see in my code, I'll surely take away everything I can.
I've edited the question adding updated code. It works now, I hope there's nothing wrong in code writing now.